# Elasticsearch server stops due to java.io.IOException break

Tags: elasticsearch

I am facing problems with Elasticsearch.
I am unable to get the results. I checked in log files i got the following error:

```
ERROR:
2014-10-30 08:52:46,971][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [Lianda] [135] Failed to execute fetch phase
[Error: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd").getInputStream(): Cannot run program "cd": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory]
[Near : {... w InputStreamReader(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd" ....}]
```

Below are the version I am using:

- elastic search version: 0.90.5
- java version: 1.6.0_33 64 bit
- plugin installed: phonetic

The strange thing is that, whenever I am getting this error, I restart the elastic search server and its works.

So I think something is getting overloaded.

Answer (score 2):

Based on seeing the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` call, it could be related to a dynamic scripting vulnerability in the defaults of elastic search prior to version 1.2. See this document on [scripting security](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/scripting-security/).

If that is the source of your problem, you can put in a fix in your current version (or upgrade to a newer version).  From the link above:

> If you are running an Elasticsearch node prior to the 1.2.x release,
>   you can make this change on your system by putting the following
>   setting into elasticsearch.yml:
>
> ```
> script.disable_dynamic: true
> ```
>
> Then restart each node in your cluster. Dynamic scripting will now be
>   disabled. If you are running Elasticsearch 1.2.x or later, dynamic
>   scripting is already disabled by default.